# mathools with lineno

Tags: mathtools, lineno

The following MWE

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lineno,lipsum}
\usepackage{mathtools}  % commenting this resolves the issue

\linenumbers
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\lipsum[2] \[A=B\]

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

Has line numbers on the first and third paragraph but not the second. It seems that the culprit is `mathtools` since commenting the `usepackage` commad resolves the issue. But how do I get `lineno` to work with `mathtools`?

PS: Using TeX Live 2020

Comment: Perhaps load `lineno` after `mathtools`?

Comment: Duh!! I should have tried this. This is annoying. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: That said, I have no idea what the reason is

Comment: @daleif Can you make your `comment` as an answer? so that it will help any one in future...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue it actually not realyed to `mathtools` at all, but the fact that `mathtools` loads `amsmath`.

It you make sure `lineno` is loaded **after** `amsmath` (or `mathtools`) then things seems to be working againg.

Note: as Ulrike mentions in the comments, loading `lineno` last will redefine certain constructions such that they are no longer robust. Whether this is a problem is hard to tell.

Comment: but then \[ will no longer be robust (and probably some other math environments), as lineno redefines it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I know, You have a better solution? I don't want to stick my hand into `lineno`. (wouldn't that be easier to implement in lualatex?)

Comment: well one could manually add the environment `\begin{linenomath}\[A=B\]\end{linenomath}`.